# Make a button in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, action

This is a repeat question.  I have tried several answers by copying and pasting into x-code.  Yet my button actions never get called.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    button.setTitle("Test Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(button)
}  

func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!) {
    println("Button tapped") {
}
```

Any idea why this does not work?

Comment: That's odd, it looks correct to me. Are you able to tap the button in the UI?

Comment: It seems like I can't.  I added a different title for UIControlState.Highlighted and the title does not change.  Is there another way I should be checking?

Comment: Also, buttons that I make in a xib do not work either after dragging to create the IBAction.

Comment: If I don't remove the storyboard from the project, but create the button programmatically, it works.  So it seems like my problem is in getting rid of the storyboard.  Although I do that in every objective-c project I make.  So not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Then if i add another UIViewController subclass and instantiate and present programmatically, all of my programmatically created buttons in the new view controller work.

Answer (score 0):

`buttonAction` is not bound to any ui element here. You need to add `@IBAction`, like this:

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
```

After that, press (and keep pressed) the ctrl key on your keyboard, then click and drag from your button (you should see a blue line stretching from it) until you reach the `buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)` text. You should see a blue rectangle appearing around the text. Release mouse and key. If you see a black dot in the gutter (the vertical strip beside the line numbers) you're done!

Comment: OP is not using Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
```

Use:

```
let button = UIButton(type: .System)
```

With that change, your code worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
```